# How do i get the bounding rect of each word in a text (for reading eyetracking)?

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

For an eye tracking study i need the positions of each word in a text drawn to the window. 
I can see how I can get the bounding box of the whole text as a return value using

```
[nx, ny, textbounds] = DrawFormattedText(win, tstring)
```

Is there a better way than drawing a whole sentence using this function word by word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
teststr = {'Hello World!' ; 'How are you doing?'}

ystart = 100
xstart = 200
wordgap = 10

for i=1:size(teststr,1)

  str=teststr{i};
  wordlist = strsplit(str , ' ');

  for j=1:size(wordlist)(1)
    [nx, ny, textbounds]=DrawFormattedText(win, wordlist{j} ,xstart, ystart);
    poslist{j} = textbounds;
    xstart=nx+wordgap;
  end

end
```

Not pretty, but it works. You will get problems if you have linebreaks.

EDIT: 2015-07-14: added wordgap suggestion from  `sven.io`

Comment: probably a little whitespace between the words would be required, like  `wordgap = 10`. 
and nx and ny are the top left corner of the drawn text, so `xstart = nx + textbounds.width + wordgap;` i would expect?

Comment: "The function returns the new (nx, ny) position of the text drawing cursor
and the bounding rectangle 'textbounds' of the drawn string. (nx,ny) can
be used as new start position for connecting further text strings to the
bottom of the drawn text string." The wordgap is a good hint!